# How to compare encrypted data formed from codeigniter 3.1.11 encrypt library through mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have used,

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$result = $this->encrypt->encode($data);
```

to encrypt data and saved to my data base.

```
$this->encrypt->decode($data);
```

to decrypt data

But when i tried to search for a email in my table which already exits returned 0 results ,because  encrypt returns different string every time.So i just want to know if there is any mysql function which can compare encrypted data in MYsql or the alternative method to compare encrypted string

Comment: Even if English isn't your first language, I expect you to be able to spell `library` because it is in your code. I expect you to be able to spell `CodeIgniter` because it is spelled for you in the question tag.  Please care more about the question that you post so that other people don't need to clean up after you.

Comment: totally agree with you ,it was a typing mistake.so do you have a solution for this?@mickmackusa

Comment: You are using an application level encryption, which the database has no visibility and knowledge of. All mysql can see is the encrypted data. You have to decrypt your data on the application level and search the data on application level. Mysql enterprise comes with transparent database encryption, which protects data at rest, yet enables mysql to query it on the fly. This however, offers a different level of security as the unencrypted data will be available for all users with a valid login to mysql.

Comment: @Shadow do we get any combination like ( SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(" . $password . ")))) so that we can compare if we know the key used to encrypt

Comment: If your encryption is deterministic (no salt, same IV), then you can just search for the encrypted form of the email. If it is non-deterministic, it will need to be decrypted first. If the encryption happens in the application, that's where the decryption must happen, too, unless you can translate your encryption algorithm to the database layer. What you just posted is hashing, not encryption. Other options include [blind indexes](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql)

Comment: You can use any functions implemented in your mysql version. However, even if the function is supposed to do what its php equivalent does, there is no guarantee that their outputs will match.

Comment: @shadow@chris Hass please advice the best way to achieve this, i need my data in encrypted form in mysql and when i retrieve and print i need it in decrypted form also i need to compare data inside tables like email id, phone number

Comment: We cannot advise you on the 'best' way! You have to decide based on the comments what level of encryption you need (application or db level), and whether you need full matching only or partial / pattern based matching, and then choose the right the approach best for you. To be honest, if you are serious about needing encryption, hire somebody, who is experienced with cryptography as it is very easy to get stuff wrong and have a false sense of security!